# Tried this with pyQt5(python 3.6), but facing ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pyqt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel('\tHello World!')
    window.setCentralWidget(label)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Tried executing after installing pyqt5 through cmd "pip install pyqt5" and "pip install pyqt5-tools"

image showing the error has been attached here

[image]

Comment: I think you have installed in a python different from the one you use in pycharm.

Comment: Go to `File / Settings` and under `Project: untitled1` check what `Project Interpreter` is selected - you need to select the one that has `pyqt5` installed (or create a virtual environment and install one there).

Comment: Thanks for the response.

First time I did as eyllanesc mentioned and then before posting this question I uninstalled and reinstalled everything (python 3.6, pycharm community version).

@zwer also I did as you told ...by watching a YouTube video before posting this qsn